# Стилизация Яндекс Карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Можно ли стилизовать яндекс карты таким образом ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если да, то пример кода пжл.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос к тех поддержки  `yandex карты`

Comment: @Air так три четверти вопросов на ruSO можно закрыть с формулировкой вида «потому что вопрос к техподдержке %технологиянейм%» от Windows до React

Comment: @Air вы не правы, так действительно все вопросы можно перенаправить к производителям/мэинтейнерам всего софта и технологий.

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете получить любое изображение карты, отрисованной через API, используя дополнительный подготовленный слой. Пример реализации кастомной карты можно посмотреть здесь:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map

Comment: Всё же это не совсем стилизация, а использование собственных тайлов, что, в большинстве случаев, проблематично.

Answer (score 1):

Именно так, скорее всего, не получится, но можно немного *поиграть с цветами* используя [вот эту технику](https://snipp.ru/view/183).

Так же стоит почитать про [использование SVG-фильтров](https://css-tricks.com/color-filters-can-turn-your-gray-skies-blue/).